# Blaze only client-side with routing

Tags: meteor, iron-router, meteor-blaze, flow-router

did anyone here tried using Blaze as a stand-alone framework?

I just love the simplicity of Blaze. I would like to use it as client-side only and there is a guide for it but there is no example for routing.

Is there any guide or SO question for it? Or does anyone know if you can even achieve it with a simple yes/no answer that would be great.

Thanks.